# Jira access with AJP-Proxy

Tags: mod-proxy, ajp, jira

I want to configure the Jira-Access over AJP-Proxy. I 'm following this [howto](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Apache+Reverse+Proxy+Using+the+AJP+Protocol)

1. In the server.xml I activate the AJP:

   `<Connector port="8089" redirectPort="8444" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>`
2. Edit VHOST configuration:

   ```
   # Load Proxy-Modules
   LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
   LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

   # Load AJP-Modules
   LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so


   # Proxy Configuration

   <IfModule proxy_http_module>
       ProxyRequests Off
       ProxyPreserveHost On

       # Basic AuthType configuration
       <Proxy *>
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName Bamboo-Server
           AuthUserFile /var/www/userdb
           Require valid-user

           AddDefaultCharset off
           Order deny,allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from 192.168.0.1
           satisfy any
       </Proxy>

       ProxyPass        /bamboo http://localhost:8085/bamboo
       ProxyPassReverse /bamboo http://localhost:8085/bamboo

       ProxyPass        /jira ajp://localhost:8009/
       ProxyPassReverse /jira ajp://localhost:8009/
   </IfModule>
   ```

But it doesn't work.

In the logs, I found:

```
//localhost:8080/
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:13 2010] [debug] proxy_util.c(1819): proxy: worker ajp://localhost:8080/ already initialized
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:13 2010] [debug] proxy_util.c(1913): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 5578 for (localhost)
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:32 2010] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:32 2010] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:32 2010] [debug] proxy_util.c(2008): proxy: AJP: has released connection for (localhost)
[Fri Nov 19 14:51:32 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client xx.xx.xx.xx Zlib: Compressed 468 to 320 : URL /jira
```

Somebody have an idea?

Comment: How about logs from the Jira side?

Answer (score 2):

Have you got the right port there? There are two different connectors in the JIRA server XML. The HTTP one is on 8080 by default.

The AJP one is normally 8009 by default:

```
<Connector port="8009" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
 maxSpareThreads="75" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" enableLookups="false"  
 redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
 disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

**EDIT**

Now you have the right port it appears to be a protocol problem. I would verify that the proxy_ajp_module is loading correctly:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

You might want to move all of your proxy settings out of the `<IfModule proxy_http_module>` section to test too.

Answer (score 0):

I have active the AJP-Connetor in JIRA server-xml:

```
<Connector port="8089" redirectPort="8444" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

The Port 8009 are also listening: 
    netstat -ntpl | grep 8009
    tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8009          :::*                    LISTEN      20767/java

**EDIT**
Oh shit, I´m bliend :-/ Know I understand what U mean. I´ve edit the wrong port ... I will try it immediately

**EDIT2**
I have now change the Port in the server.xml

```
<Connector port="8009" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
maxSpareThreads="75" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" enableLookups="false"
redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000"
disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

But it dosen´t work! I became a Internal **Server Error**. 
In the Apache log, i found this error:
`No protocol handler was valid for the URL`

Comment: sorry dont mean to repeat but 8089 you have in your server xml is not the 8009 that you are expecting in your apache config

Answer (score 0):

Your apache with ajp is probably trying to connect to the port mentioned via ipv4, while the service is only listening on ipv6...